# how to set validation on button current title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

hi i am new in iphone development,and i have task to develop the uibutton and picker relational application.

i have to develop the one view which have the button 1 uipicker view. when i run the application at that time the title of the button is blank. if the user directly click to submit the button at that time user will get the error message.

but i can get the error msg and my following code is not working it is submiting the form without checking the button text validation.

following is my code:

```
if ([btnPicker.currentTitle isEqualToString:@" "]) {

     UIAlertView *alertPicker = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Required" message:@"Please,Select Month & Date." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
     [alertPicker show];
     NSLog(@"%@", alertPicker);
     [alertPicker release];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[btnPicker.currentTitle isEqualToString:@""];
```

or

```
if ([btnPicker.currentTitle length]==0)
```

Comment: My +1 is for the second option - the first option will return `NO` if the string is `nil` but the second one will detect both `nil` and `@""` strings - it's almost certainly going to be OK in this case but it's good practice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually a blank string is an *empty string* `@""` not a *space* `@" "`.  You have to test an empty string like this,

```
[btnPicker.currentTitle isEqualToString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be  `[btnPicker.currentTitle isEqualToString:@""]` ? String without the space?